# Mulesoft update application downtime

Tags: mule

I want to update a mule application via MMC. When I deploy what will be the impact of the already running Mule flow. Will is gracefully complete and new once take the new one or will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MMC with cluster environment and your deployment application working fine then it will automatically adjust the downtime.